# Google Cloud Billing Project based report

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-billing

In Google Cloud Platform, is there any way to generate Project based billed report. Can able to find only overall billed report which includes particulars for all Projects instead of project based. If available in PDF format it will be easy to mail to corresponding project monthly.

PS All project is being paid by single Billing Account.

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly stated, the billing is per billing account and not per project. There is a very nice feature which allows you to [export](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293835?hl=en) your billing information in CSV or JSON format stored in a Google Cloud Storage bucket. These files can be parsed, processed and analyzed.

There are even some applications like [MyBillingExplorer](http://www.mybillingexplorer.com/) that know how to parse these files and provide UI for analysis.

Disclaimer: I am the CTO of [DoIT International](http://www.doit-intl.com) which also happens to develop the MyBillingExplorer tool.